# how to resize the modal popup image in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to resize the image for my custom newsletter popup so that if user upload a bigger image from my custom system configuration it will not disturb the popup design.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS max-width property

```
#image_id {
     max-widht:300px; //max widht as you like
}
```